# Eclipse RCP App : Adding Wizard Page (single page)

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I'm new to Eclipse RCP development, have a question :

I have written a Simple RCP application with a View.
But I want WizardPage instead view when this standalone Eclipse RCP app starts.
(page with Ok, Cancel and some labels + texts)

Any pointers?? Thanks in advance

Comment: nothing out of box available, for now implemeted using placing controls in composites with OK, Cancel button with tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Just Google for the *"Eclipse wizard"* expression. This is a [quite extensive tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-custwiz/), but there are quite a lot of important details in the official on-line [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/dialogs.htm&cp=2_0_5) documentation.